# Artifacts appear when I use the subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm (almost) a complete newbie in Blender. I thought that modelling a greek column would be a great exercise for me. My mesh doesn't look so bad, but when I subdivide everything, some strange artifacts appear :(

Here is an example:
[image]

Also, here is a link to my .blend file, so you can see the mesh:
[.blend file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=99953488615376293200)
Could you give me some advice how to remove those strange things? :/

Comment: In *Edit Mode* without any vertices selected, press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+M to select all [non-manifold](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/2843) vertices. You have to fix these...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that along the object you have large and ugly **[ngons](http://blog.digitaltutors.com/ngons-triangles-bad/)** (polygons with more than 4 vertices). Ngons don't work so well with the subsurf modifier.

Use quads instead to connect all of the other vertices, that will give you a nicer edge flow:

[image]

[image]